# Integral of a product of two multivariate normal distributions where one has shifted mean

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, normal-distribution

I'm stuck trying to compute the following integral for any $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2} \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$ \int \int dxdp e^{-\frac{1}{2}((x-\alpha_{1})^{2} + (p-\alpha_{1})^{2}) }e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+p^{2})}$$

It's variation of the famous Gaussian integral.

I've tried combining the exponents as

${((x-\alpha_{1})^{2} + (p-\alpha_{1})^{2}) } +{(x^{2}+p^{2})} = (2x^{2}-2\alpha_{1}x + \alpha_{1}^{2}) + (2p^{2}-2\alpha_{2}p + \alpha_{2}^{2})$
but that hasn't helped much....

Comment: you get $ - (x^2 - \alpha x + \alpha^2 /2)$. Rewrite it as $- (x - \alpha/2)^2 - \alpha^2/4$. The last term is $e^{- \alpha^2/4}$ which is a constant and can be taken out. Similarly do for $p$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that in a moment and see what I get.